# How to obtain number of packets dropped over past 30 seconds

Tags: bash, iptables

I am programmatically dropping packets on an interface with an IP table rule (dropping packets coming in with a 50% probability). I want to be able to get the number of dropped packets over the past 3 seconds using a bash script. I've already looked at ifstat but it doesnt seem to be recognizing that drops are occurring (maybe it looks at the packets coming in only after going through IPtables?). Are there other tools or utilities that I could use to get a number like that?

Edit: I should mention that iptables is a tool that I am using to simulate a high speed network that can make the recipient start to drop packets due to sheer volume. This situation is what I want to look at and be able to identify.

Answer (score 3):

Use dumpcap for this :

```
dumpcap  -i your_interface_here -a duration:3 -w log.pcap | grep '^Packets received/dropped'
```

`dumpcap manpage says:`

> -a
>   
>              Specify a criterion that specifies when Dumpcap is to stop writing
>              to a capture file.  The criterion is of the form test:value, where
>              test is one of:
>
> ```
>        duration:value Stop writing to a capture file after value seconds
>        have elapsed.
> ```
>
> -i
>    capture interface
>   -w  
>              Write raw packet data to outfile.

Comment: Does not appear to answer OP's question. He seems to be looking for stats on packets dropped, not trying to capture them.

Comment: @Shadowfen: You sure ? imho the op is looking for `I want to be able to get the number of dropped packets over the past 3 seconds using a bash script.`

Comment: The "number of dropped packets" - not capturing the packets.

Comment: @Shadowfen : By the way, even though the `dumpcap` writes raw packet data to log file , at the end of the capture it also gives a nice clean stat of what happened from which we are grabbing the line which contains info about packets dropped Actually it will be of the format `Packets Received/Dropped 100/20`

Comment: I was under the impression that the dumpcap stat about packets dropped tells you how many packets that dumpcap was unable to capture, which might be higher than how many packets were dropped (comparing drop rates for instance) when dumpcap was not run.

Comment: @Shadowfen I am not looking for the actual packets (at least for right now) and am purely interested in the statistics of the drops. This process is going to be run on a machine where writing to a file every time a packet is dropped is way too resource-intensive. In your last comment, I agree. I have been looking at TCPdump for raw stats but wanted to get away from logging all the packets. Because TCPdump has to process all the packets, it looks at the dropped packets that it wasn't able to process, so that number is much higher than the actual drop stats.

Comment: @Shadowfen do you know of a tool that can do this? Ifstat and netstat don't show the packets being dropped by iptables or nc

Comment: No, that is one reason I  was following this thread with interest. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `iptables -vL`, it shows dropped packet count by iptable rule.

```
s1=$(iptables -vL |  grep rule | awk '{ print $1}')
sleep 3
s2=$(iptables -vL |  grep rule | awk '{ print $1}')
echo "$(($s2-$s1))"
```

**rule** stands for defined rules in iptables.

Comment: While this may work with the specific scenario that I am dropping packets with IPtables, in the long run, iptables is supposed to simulate a situation where my network is running at a speed high enough that the interface starts to drop packets. So using the iptables methods wouldn't work in that situation because packets are dropped not by rules but due to sheer volume.